# Ansible on Ubuntu Core

Tags: ansible

Ubuntu Core is a minimalistic operating system. It uses `snap` package manager instead of `apt`.
Is it possible to manage a Ubuntu Core device with Ansible?

Comment: [snap](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/snap_module.html#snap-manages-snaps) should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the OS has a python installation, you can use  [Ansible to manage it.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements). Note that you should check the individual module requirements (for example the [snap module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements)) since they may have dependencies which cannot be satisfied by your OS.

In general though the modules are written in python and as such a python runtime is needed.